# Спарсить <script type="text/javascript" python

Tags: python

1. Нужно спарсить значение screen_name.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="YjJmNTAwODgtODBmMy00YzQ5LWJhODItMmQwNTk0Yjg4MTI1">window.__INITIAL_STATE__={"optimist":[],"urt":{},"toasts":[],"needs_phone_verification":false,"normal_followers_count":2,"notifications":false,"pinned_tweet_ids_str":[],"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1174197230003208192/qK5cqalJ_normal.jpg","profile_interstitial_type":"","protected":false,"screen_name":"Vickson25435099"};</script>
```

2. Пытаюсь спарсить так:

```
import requests
import json


x = requests.get('https://twitter.com/home')
html = x.text.split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')[0]
html = html.split(';</script>')[0]
data = json.loads(html)
print(data['screen_name'])
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
```

На выходе нужно получить только Vickson25435099

вот вся html страница [тык](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_7VT2MMmtlGbDZOtXtOnP_imSNiAWn-4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: может вам все-таки задуматься об использовании Beautiful Soup и не изобретать колесо?

Comment: @strawdog тоже не получается...

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` я вам вроде загрузил:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = requests.get('https://twitter.com/home')
b = BeautifulSoup(x.text)
for s in b.find_all('script'):
    wis = s.text.split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')
    if len(wis) > 1:
        data = json.loads(wis[1].split(';')[0])
```

Comment: а как вывести screen_name ? не получается

Comment: @jorkia А что у вас в `data` получается при использовании моего кода?

Comment: ну я в конце добавил print(data) получаю: NameError: name 'data' is not defined.

Comment: b = BeautifulSoup(x.text) и если сюда не добавить lxml или html.parser то будет ошибка

Comment: и попробовал просто так ещё. print(wis['screen_name'] получаю такую ошибку TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Странно, у меня этот код в Google Colab работает, `data` заполняется, но поскольку это обращение к незалогиненному твиттеру, там нет данных пользователя

Comment: в любом случае при print(data['screen_name']) вот такая ошибка local variable 'data' referenced before assignment. К залогиненому твиттеру

Comment: Это после выполнения всего цикла вы делаете? Значит, что-то не срабатывает, в `if` с `json.loads` управление не попадает. Поставьте `print` с чем-нибудь после каждой строки кода и отследите что происходит.

Comment: код в точности такой же как вы скинули. Если не чего не менять сыпять ошибка бс4 и 'data' is not defined. Если добавить в бс4 lxml ошибок бс4 пропадают. Если поменять for s на b и s.text.split на x.text.split. То дата работает, и в принте выводиться всё после window.__INITIAL_STATE__=

Comment: Всё теперь просто data выводится. А как вывести именно то что в screen_name ?

Comment: `print(data['screen_name'])` вот такое не работает